# Browser Back button does not fire componentDidMount() React life cycle method

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have react with redux app the gets a list of order items from Rest API and put on array filled with redux. There is a link in the same list that navigates to the details of an order. When navigating to the details and press the browser back button in order to load the list again I got the following error.

> TypeError: fetchedOrders.map is not a function

this is the code inside orders list container

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.handleFetchOrders(1);
    }

render() {

  { fetchedOrders && fetchedOrders.map(order => {
            return (
              <OrdersWE
                order={order}
                onDelete={onDelete}
                history = {this.props.history}
                key={order.OrderHID}
              />
            );
          })}

}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {    
    handleFetchOrders: (pageNumber) => {
      dispatch(fetchOrders(pageNumber));
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Don't post snippets of the code, you should always add a reproducible example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will try to enhance the posted code

Comment: What is `fetchedOrders`? There's no way to understand what it is with the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `return` statement from `render` function, also you have to return a single `ReactElement`:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {fetchedOrders &&
          fetchedOrders.map(order => {
            return (
              <OrdersWE
                order={order}
                onDelete={onDelete}
                history={this.props.history}
                key={order.OrderHID}
              />
            );
          })}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Moreover, try to log `fetchedOrders`, according to the error it may be not an array object.

Comment: thanks for your comment. The return is missed here because I have picked part of the code and forgot to put here but its already existing.

Comment: @MohamedDawaina Please edit the question to reflect this, otherwise it's misleading people trying to help.